# How to convert ArrayList to pointer to pointer in JNI, and how to convert c++ class to jobject?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I need to use C++ native method in an Android Project. The C++ part provides the following function declaration:

```
void func(InputData **inputs, OutData *outputs);
```

InputData and OutData are my self-defined C++ class. The function will read datas from inputs and write datas to outputs. I created two responding class in Java: InputData and OutData. In Java, I write the function declaration as:

```
public static native OutData getOutData(ArrayList<InputData> inputDatas)
```

In my JNI code, it will be converted to:

```
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL JAVA_package_name_getOutData(JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz,  jobject inputDatas)
```

So my question is, what is the correct way to call the C++ function?

I tried the following code:

```
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL JAVA_package_name_getOutData(JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz,  jobject inputDatas) {
    InputData ** input = (InputData **)&inputDatas;
    OutData *outData = (OutData *)malloc(neccessary_bytes);
    func(input, outData);
    return *outData;
}
```

I am not sure whether it will works because I cannot run the project now.

**EDIT**: 
Class definitions in C++:

```
struct InputData {
   uint64_t in_size;
   uint8_t *data;
}

struct OutData {
   uint64_t out_size;
   uint8_t  *data;
}
```

In Java:

```
public class InputData{
    public double in_size;
    public byte[] data;
}

public class OutData {
    public double out_size;
    public byte[] data;
}
```

Comment: You can't map C++ class instances to Java class instances or vice versa just by casting. Remember, every time you feel the urge to cast, that casting is most often the wrong tool, and it tells the compiler that you know what you're doing. If you don't know, then you're just misinforming the compiler. I suggest you start with something much simpler. A function returning an `int`. When that works, try at function returning a string, such as "Hello, cruel JNI world!".

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, so I need to use (*env)->NewObject to create a Java class instance , and copy outData to it, right?

Comment: Like that, yes. But instead of trying that directly, get something simple to work first. Always a good idea, and the reason for the incredible immense popularity of otherwise good-for-nothing "Hello, world!".

Comment: Show us what Input and OutputData look like in Java. Add the Java classes.

Comment: @Brandon I have added the class definition both in Java and C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given (Java):

```
public class InputData {
    public long in_size;
    public byte[] data;
}

public class OutData {
    public long out_size;
    public byte[] data;
}
```

Then C++:

```
struct InputData
{
    uint64_t in_size;
    uint8_t *data;
};

struct OutputData
{
    uint64_t out_size;
    uint8_t  *data;
};


OutputData* inputsToOutput(InputData** inputs, int numInputs)
{
    //Do whatever here to convert them..
    return NULL;
}


//Convert a Java inputData to C++ inputData
InputData* JavaInToCppIn(JNIEnv* env, jobject inputData)
{
    jclass cls = env->GetObjectClass(inputData);
    jlong in_size = env->GetLongField(inputData, env->GetFieldID(cls, "in_size", "J"));
    jarray arr = static_cast<jarray>(env->GetObjectField(inputData, env->GetFieldID(cls, "data", "[B")));
    jsize arrSize = env->GetArrayLength(arr);

    if (in_size != arrSize)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    InputData* inData = new (std::nothrow) InputData();

    if (inData)
    {
        inData->in_size = in_size;
        inData->data = new (std::nothrow) uint8_t[arrSize];

        if (inData->data)
        {
            void* ptr = env->GetPrimitiveArrayCritical(arr, NULL);
            memcpy(inData->data, ptr, sizeof(uint8_t) * arrSize);
            env->ReleasePrimitiveArrayCritical(arr, ptr, 0);
            return inData;
        }

        delete inData;
    }
    return NULL;
}

//Convert a Java OutputData to C++ OutputData
OutputData* JavaOutToCppOut(JNIEnv* env, jobject outputData)
{
    jclass cls = env->GetObjectClass(outputData);
    jlong out_size = env->GetLongField(outputData, env->GetFieldID(cls, "out_size", "J"));
    jarray arr = static_cast<jarray>(env->GetObjectField(outputData, env->GetFieldID(cls, "data", "[B")));
    jsize arrSize = env->GetArrayLength(arr);

    if (out_size != arrSize)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    OutputData* outData = new (std::nothrow) OutputData();

    if (outData)
    {
        outData->out_size = out_size;
        outData->data = new (std::nothrow) uint8_t[arrSize];

        if (outData->data)
        {
            void* ptr = env->GetPrimitiveArrayCritical(arr, NULL);
            memcpy(outData->data, ptr, sizeof(uint8_t) * arrSize);
            env->ReleasePrimitiveArrayCritical(arr, ptr, 0);
            return outData;
        }

        delete outData;
    }
    return NULL;
}

//Convert a C++ InputData to Java InputData
jobject CppInToJavaIn(JNIEnv* env, InputData* inData)
{
    jclass cls = env->FindClass("Lpackage/Name/InputData;");
    jobject res = env->NewObject(cls, env->GetMethodID(cls, "<init>", "()V"));
    env->SetLongField(res, env->GetFieldID(cls, "in_size", "J"), inData->in_size);

    jbyte* ptr = reinterpret_cast<jbyte*>(inData->data);
    jbyteArray arr = env->NewByteArray(inData->in_size);
    env->SetByteArrayRegion(arr, 0, inData->in_size, ptr);
    env->SetObjectField(res, env->GetFieldID(cls, "data", "[B"), arr);

    return res;
}

//Convert a C++ OutputData to a Java OutputData
jobject CppOutToJavaOut(JNIEnv* env, OutputData* outData)
{
    jclass cls = env->FindClass("Lpackage/Name/OutputData;");
    jobject res = env->NewObject(cls, env->GetMethodID(cls, "<init>", "()V"));
    env->SetLongField(res, env->GetFieldID(cls, "out_size", "J"), outData->out_size);

    jbyte* ptr = reinterpret_cast<jbyte*>(outData->data);
    jbyteArray arr = env->NewByteArray(outData->out_size);
    env->SetByteArrayRegion(arr, 0, outData->out_size, ptr);
    env->SetObjectField(res, env->GetFieldID(cls, "data", "[B"), arr);

    return res;
}


//Get Inputs from an ArrayList, convert them to an OutputData.
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL JAVA_package_name_getOutData(JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz,  jobject inputDatas)
{
    jclass arrayListClass = env->FindClass("Ljava/util/ArrayList;");
    int arrayListSize = env->CallIntMethod(inputDatas, env->GetMethodID(arrayListClass, "size", "()I"));

    if (arrayListSize > 0)
    {
        //Array of C++ inputs from Java..
        InputData** inputs = new (std::nothrow) InputData*[arrayListSize];

        if (inputs)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < arrayListSize; ++i)
            {
                jobject jinput = env->NewGlobalRef(env->CallObjectMethod(inputDatas, env->GetMethodID(arrayListClass, "get", "(I)Ljava/lang/Object;"), i));

                inputs[i] = JavaInToCppIn(env, jinput);

                env->DeleteGlobalRef(jinput);
            }

            //Conver the C++ inputs to a C++ output, and then convert that C++ output into a Java OutputData.
            OutputData* out = inputsToOutput(inputs, arrayListSize);
            jobject output = CppOutToJavaOut(env, out);


            //Clean-Up.
            for (int i = 0; i < arrayListSize; ++i)
            {
                if (inputs[i])
                {
                    delete[] inputs[i]->data;
                }
                delete inputs[i];
            }

            delete[] inputs;
            delete out;

            return output;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Note: I used C++'s `new` and `delete` instead of `malloc` and `free`, but I kept it as `nothrow` so that you can "check" if the allocation succeeded rather than it throwing an exception.. Also note, I did not use `std::unique_ptr` or `std::vector` or any constructors/destructors/RAII stuff because I do not know your restrictions on containers or anything..

Comment: Thank you very much, your code is a magic! It runs so well that I don't need to modify even a character.